# Application layers. Mapping between api models and internal models

Tags: rest, spring-boot, design-patterns, architecture, software-design

I have situation like this

I have controller code

```
@RestController
public class MyController implements SomeApi {

@Autowired
private final MyService myService ;

 public ResponseEntity<AnswerObject> getSomething (RestModelObject obj) {
    myService.getSomething(obj);
}
```

Below Service code:

```
@Service
public class MyServiceImpl implements MyService {

@Autowired
private final EntityRepository entityRepository;

 public AnswerObject getSomething (RestModelObject obj) {
        Entity entity = entityRepository.getSomething(obj);
        AnswerObject answerObject = map(entity, new AnswerObject());
        return answerObject;
        }
}
```

I have here few layers as I can see - rest layer, business layer, persistence layer (let's suppose I have few data sources - DB and elastic, each have some repository bean).

As we can see Business layer (service) aware about entities, which is not really good I think.

So question is what is the best practices for this situation?
Mapping should happen on persistence layer?

Or Is it good idea to create some additional layer adapter which will be responsible for mappings between rest models to internal data models, and inject it to the service bean ?

Appreciate any good mature examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, it can be done on controller's level, like in example [here](https://www.baeldung.com/entity-to-and-from-dto-for-a-java-spring-application). Correct me If I am wrong.